# Build without requiring users to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: mojave, path, library, environment-variables

I'm following [this guide](https://www.elliottforney.com/blog/npspmkl/) on how to build NumPy with Intel MKL on a macOS (I'm on Mojave 10.14.5), and after installing Intel's MKL library, the guide tells me to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

The problem is, if I now build NumPy and share it to someone else, they will have to set this same environment variable manually. How can I automate this process so it's enough that they install Intel's MKL tools into `/opt/intel/mkl` without having to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Why not use a package manager like macports homebrew or anaconda rather than do it yourself. They will all have installation instructions.

Comment: @Mark I need a very specific version (I have existing code base on windows, needs to be ported to mac with same versions) that wasn't available on any package manager or anaconda.